# comparison of audio mp3 file with recorded wav file

Tags: bluetooth, mp3, wav

I have a setup which plays an mp3 on a platform. The music is streamed via Bluetooth and recorded as a .wav file

My objective is to test the quality of the Bluetooth chip by comparing how well the recorded .wav file matches with the mp3 being played on the device. Since this is a recording the starting of the original and recorded may not be exactly aligned.

Is it a feasible concept to compare two files with same audio content stored in different format, with different sampling rates?

If i were to analyse the waveform and spectrogram of the two, would i be able to judge the quality of streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure to understand where the matter is, I mean sampling rate is already a clear indicator of the quality. Now I assume you are worried your techno might not read a compressed MP3 which should be smaller than a WAV from my memories.

In which case you need to compare granularity of the output music (effective sampling rate perceived). of course assuming you inputed a wav and mp3 with the same initial sampling rate.

Comment: so what is the best way to check granularity, which in turn differentiates a good bluetooth chip from a bad one. will checking the waveform help?